# how to find big file and delete on linux system

Tags: linux, mercurial-bigfiles, sda

When I install something in my linux system( **CentOS release 6.5 (Final)** ).It happens.

Error Downloading Packages:
  ncdu-1.7-1.el6.x86_64: Insufficient space in download directory    /var/cache/yum/epel/packages .

And I use *df* command,it shows:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        77G   73G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       239M   43M  183M  19% /boot
```

sda2 was mounted on /,but when I go to the root and use command *du*.

```
du -sh *
6.2M    bin
41M boot
176K    dev
26M etc
488K    export
6.7G    home
268M    lib
19M lib64
16K lost+found
4.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
56M opt
du: cannot access `proc/1531/task/1531/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/1531/task/1531/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/1531/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/1531/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/6873/task/7037/fd/125': No such file or directory
0   proc
640K    root
9.0M    sbin
4.0K    selinux
4.0K    srv
0   sys
569M    tmp
1.4G    usr
261M    var
4.0K    zookeeper_server.pid
```

where is my 77G gone? how do I find my big file and delete?

Comment: Do you setup logrotate on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot afford to reboot your server, this command shall help you :

```
lsof | grep "/var" | grep deleted
```

It will show you if there is any deleted file still in memory, and help you find which service has to be restarted.

If that is an option, a server reboot can also solve the problem.